# how do I write mongoD query for getting data of sum of stock and minimum price of the batch where stock is available?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```json
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "61ca99503b86b1c08d16ac14"
    },
    "sku_code": "500559",
    "sku_name": "Johnson's Baby Cream 100gm",
    "store_sku_id": "500559_176",
    "ofc_code": 176,
    "vars": [
      {
        "sku_available_unit": 0,
        "batch_no": 4592,
        "default_price": 135,
        "list_price": 135,
        "disc_percentage": 0
      },
      {
        "sku_available_unit": 10,
        "batch_no": 4591,
        "default_price": 140,
        "list_price": 140,
        "disc_percentage": 0
      },
      {
        "sku_available_unit": 10,
        "batch_no": 4593,
        "default_price": 145,
        "list_price": 145,
        "disc_percentage": 0
      }
    ],
    "camp_code": null,
    "camp_type": null
  }
]
```

expected to show output as 20.
also I am trying to find minimum list_price from the availablestock like in the above  case output as 140 .as 140is minimum of availablestock.

Comment: You can write an aggregation query with `$unwind` and `$group` stages - and use aggregation operators like `$sum`, `$min`, etc. See: [Aggregation Reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/)

Comment: Other than the sample document, we will also need to know your expected output and the logic behind. Please help to add more details to your question.

Comment: expected output as 20.

Comment: as I am new to mongodb and learning from basics.I tried this query
> db.Product.aggregate([{"$project": {"totalStock": {"$sum": "$vars.sku_available_unit"}}}])

Comment: getting this output--{ "_id" : ObjectId("61ca99503b86b1c08d16ac14"), "totalStock" : 20 } Thanks for the help @prasad_

Comment: Thanks @ray I am new to this community .Next time I try my best to give all details in proper manner.

Comment: Please don't post the update in the comments. Instead, use the edit button to post your updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `$project` to map your output. With a `$sum` on the `sku_available_unit` field you should get your total stocks.
And to get the minimun price you could use a `$min`. however, because you only want the minimun that have stock, you should apply a `$filter` operator before using the `$min`.

[Example playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dQqROm41slJ)

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$project": {
    "totalStock": {
      $sum: "$vars.sku_available_unit"
    },
    "filteredVars": {
      $filter: {
        input: "$vars",
        as: "v",
        cond: {
          $gt: [
            "$$v.sku_available_unit",
            0
          ]
        },
        
      }
    },
    
  }
},
{
  $project: {
    "minimum_list_price": {
      $min: "$filteredVars.list_price"
    },
    totalStock: 1
  }
})
```